# How to access all data and edit meta data for social accounts in auth0?

Tags: reactjs, axios, auth0

I have edited the meta data inside of my auth0 settings for one of my social facebook accounts and even see that there is a lot more information I am getting back when I use `/userinfo`.

Also I do not have access to the meta data that I set here:
[image]

I would also like to be able to update this user's meta data through my application and not have to do it through the dashboard. I do not have a `user_id` though because this is a social account logged in through the lock widget.

I am also doing this in react so it would be nice to use axios and the management api.

Answer (score 1):

You can update user metadata via the Auth0 Management API. You can also easily achieve this via auth0.js client library. [See sample here](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-single-page-app-login-with-sso-and-api/blob/master/public/javascript/index.js#L120)

Separately learn more about Auth0 Management API, and in particular [update user.](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Users/patch_users_by_id)

Finally, you may be a little confused, but even for a social connection, Auth0 will create a normalised user profile for that user - so there WILL be a user id available.

Comment: How can I access the user_id? When I log the response from `/userinfo` it is not on there.